# Tag Wiki empty after months

Tags: bug, tags

Earlier this year a low rep user created a pi-pico tag (with minimal information).
I reviewed and approved **BUT** this is still pending after 4 months!!

*The pi-pico tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?*

*You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed.*

I today created a tag for pi-pico-w with no problems in a few minutes.

This seems **bizarre** - I can create a tag, but not edit an empty tag (or even improve a placeholder).

The end result is that there IS NO TAG information for this tag!

---

There are similar bugs in Post Edits.

I can edit ANY post EXCEPT if a low rep user has already edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is one of those points where we suffer as a smaller site having to play by one-size-fits-all rules. Another one in the tag realm are [the rules around creating tag synonyms](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). The only way to realistically get it done is to post a request here and then the mods can do it, otherwise it will set in "suggested" limbo forever.

Anyway, I approved the edit that was there and improved it marginally by capitalizing the proper nouns etc. I think you should be able to edit it yourself now, lemme know if there is a further problem.

Comment: It still says "The pi-pico tag has no usage guidance, but it has a tag wiki, can you help us summarize it?" and Edit pending

Comment: It seems that although there is a  tag wiki if there is no no usage guidance no one can see it and it does not appear to be possible to create.

Comment: Yeah, that was a bit confusing.  I think whoever did the original used the same line for both the "usage guidance" and the wiki. Normally if you choose edit you get presented with both, but it seems because there was an edit pending for the the former it did not appear editable whereas the wiki was.  Approving the edit seems to have fixed things.